# Webpack CopyPlugin modifying JS Files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working on a React app being served by Flask.
I need the app to present some things that are filled by the Flask app using a Jinja template, and the simplest way I could find that *should* work is to use an external js file which I run through a `render_template` command and have the rest of the code reference that.

I used the WebpackCopyPlugin to make sure that file is available to import, and I explicitly exclude it from the babel-loader to make sure it doesn't get compiled.

However, when it is copied to the output dir by `npm run build`, it changes its contents!
This is the original file:

```js
var is_admin = "{{is_admin}}" == "True";
var is_user = "{{is_user}}" == "True";
var is_debug = "{{is_debug}}" == "True";
var username = "{{request.remote_user}}";
```

*(Yes, I know I shouldn't be keeping stuff like that in a javascript file, it doesn't actually give permissions to do anything - it's just for display purposes. The actual permission checking and access granting is all done in the backend).*

But WebpackCopyPlugin copies it to look like this:

```js
var is_admin=!1,is_user=!1,is_debug=!1,username="{{request.remote_user}}";
```

Why is it doing that?
Can I tell it to just copy the file as is without modifying it?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks more like [babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans) doing a round and figuring out that those values could never be true so it just simplifies it to false. I would try looking in that end instead.

Comment: I don't have that plugin loaded. Also, I'm having babel ignore the directory in which the `settings.js` is sitting. I tried uninstalling the plugin just in case - and it wasn't installed.

Comment: Well I guess it could be any other optimization plugin like Terser or uglify-es then. I really doubt that the copy plugin would somehow make changes to your files but it might put the files in a place that some other plugin can access it.

Comment: As a temporary workaround I have my post-build copy the original file over it, but it'd be interesting to know why this happen - there's really no plugin loaded that I think should and could be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the default minimizer options.

webpack.config.js

```
{
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      exclude: /static/,
    })]
  }
}
```